# Impute data using multiple equations (if missing)

Tags: python

Assume the following data frame:

"?"==missing value

how can i find "?" in this data frame by python and how can i handle this missing values by the bestest method, Knowing a set of relations, for example:

- col1 = cl5-col2+col4
- col6 = col3+col4
  ... and other equation and system solvers

```
    col1   col2     col3    col4    col5   col6
    20      1         ?       1      20     0
    39      1         47      0      40     1
```

Also is there a way to impute that automatically knowing that those relations are always right on each row (as in row 1 in which all values are there)

**Edit:**
I know how to calculate each one separately :

```
df.col1 = (df.col5-df.col2+df.col4) if df.col1.isna()
```

But this must be done to each column and my dataset is quite huge

Comment: To answer your question, yes.  Please show us what you’ve tried/researched and where you’re having trouble.

Comment: You are looking for a solver for linear equations? Try: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html

Comment: @S3DEV I have done that, but my solution is quite basic, I added that as an edit thanks

Comment: Conceptually your first relation could apply to all rows that had col1.isna() and did not have col2.isna() or col4 or col5.  A good first step would be figuring out how to apply that one relation.  Then you could take the same approach with each other potential relation - how many such relations do you have?